# Is there a way to change the values displayed on the legend? I'm using the leaflet package to plot a map

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm working on a shiny app that plots a map showing the number of registries per state, but when I run the code the legend displays all 37 numeric values and I've been looking for a way to group these values so the legend is smaller but can't make it work.

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DhbT.png)

This is my code:

```
library("dplyr")
library("mxmaps")
library("geojsonio")
library("jsonlite")
library("shiny")
library("leaflet")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("lubridate")
library("zoo")
library("stringi")
library("tidyverse")
library("janitor")
library("fuzzyjoin")
library("shinyWidgets")


reg <- read.csv("registries.csv")

# Group data and summarise
reg <- group_by(reg, year, month, id, state_name) %>%
  summarise(Freq = sum(Freq)) %>%
  group_by(id, state_name) %>%
  mutate(Freq = cumsum(Freq))%>%
  filter(id %in% 1:32) %>%
  mutate(reg_date = as.Date(paste0(year, "-", month, "-01"))) %>%
  mutate(mon_year = format(reg_date, "%B-%Y"))%>%
  mutate(id = str_mxstate(id))

#View(reg)

choices_month <- format(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-05-01"), by = "month", 
                                 to = as.Date("2020-06-01")), "%B-%Y")


# Convert the topoJSON to spatial object
data(mxstate.topoJSON)
tmpdir <- tempdir()
# have to use RJSONIO or else the topojson isn't valid
write(RJSONIO::toJSON(mxstate.topoJSON), file.path(tmpdir, "state.topojson"))
# read the topojson file as an 'sf' object
states <- topojson_read(file.path(tmpdir, "state.topojson"))
# put state codes in a standard format
states$id <- str_mxstate(states$id)




# Shiny app - ui 
# Define UI for application that displays registries across Mexico within a time range
ui <- bootstrapPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Registries"),

  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                sliderTextInput(inputId = "range", 
                                label = "Date:", 
                                choices = choices_month
                )
  )
)

# Shiny app - server
server <- function(input, output, session) {


  filteredData <- reactive({
    print(input$range[1])
    states <- left_join(states, subset(reg, mon_year == input$range[1]), 
                        by = "id")
    states

  })

  colorpal <- reactive({
    colorFactor(palette = c("#E6FAD7", "#AED68F", "#8ABA64", "#619A34", "#406C1F", "#203E09"), reg$Freq)
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    states <- left_join(states, subset(reg, year == 2019), by = "id")
    pal <- colorpal()
    leaflet(states) %>% addTiles() %>%
      setView(-102, 23.8, 5)%>% 
      addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                pal = pal, 
                values = ~reg$Freq, 
                title = "Number of<br/>registries per<br/>state") %>% 
      addTiles()
  })

  observe({
    pal <- colorpal()
    leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(stroke = TRUE, weight = 1, color = "#000000",
                  fillOpacity = 0.8, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                  fillColor = ~pal(Freq), 
                  popup = ~ sprintf("Estado: %s<br/>Registros: %s",
                                    stri_trans_totitle(state_name), 
                                    round(Freq, 1)))
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried adding the legend values manually as a vector but it didn't work. Also tried changing the number of bins and no success either.

You can download the CSV file from here: https://github.com/avleon/reg_data.git

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: The code is not quite reproducible to offer support. You call  values = ~reg$Freq, but you do not seem to have a dataframe named reg. reg appears to be a column in the states dataframe

Comment: @SusanSwitzer The reg dataframe pulls data from a CSV file. I've updated my code and included the link to my github repository so you can download the file. I hope the code is reproducible now. Thank you for letting me know about this issue.